# Can I get Mercurial to point out loudly that there are files I forgot to "hg add"?

Tags: mercurial

For example:

```
HG: Enter commit message.  Lines beginning with 'HG:' are removed.
HG: Leave message empty to abort commit.
HG: --
HG: user: romkyns
HG: branch 'default'
HG: UNTRACKED FILE: NewFile.xaml
HG: UNTRACKED FILE: NewFile.xaml.cs
HG: changed MainWindow.xaml.cs
HG: changed Settings.cs
```

Obviously adding those untracked files would still be optional, but hopefully this will significantly reduce the number of times I push commits with missing files.

Is there some easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Not easily, but you can indeed do it with a bit of work.

When you run `hg commit` without a given message, Mercurial will choose an editor to use based on a few things, mainly the `HGEDITOR` environement variable and the [`ui.editor` configuration setting from your `hgrc`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui).

If you point this to a script that will generate the commit message your want before running your editor of choice, you would get the expected result. The Mercurial wiki has an [article about making this work](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommitMessageTemplate) but it will only work on Mac/Linux unless you have `bash` (or some other Unix shell) running on Windows. If you know batch scripting or Powershell it should be too hard however.